# Yeti USB Microphone not recognized in Audacity or Skype 14.10

Tags: sound, 14.10, skype, alsa, microphone

cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.10"
VERSION_ID="14.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

lsusb --verbose | less

```
Bus 003 Device 008: ID b58e:9e84
```

lsmod | grep snd

```
snd_usb_audio         165943  2 
snd_usbmidi_lib        29779  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47547  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    77514  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    68988  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          30420  8 
snd_hda_controller     34275  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         139712  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              17698  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               104102  8 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30876  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                67224  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29513  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    87611  30 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              15052  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
```

cat /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xef330000 irq 46
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xef080000 irq 17
 2 [Microphone     ]: USB-Audio - Yeti Stereo Microphone
                      Blue Microphones Yeti Stereo Microphone at usb-0000:00:14.0-13, full speed
```

cat /proc/asound/pcm

```
00-00: ALC1150 Analog : ALC1150 Analog : playback 1 : capture 1
00-01: ALC1150 Digital : ALC1150 Digital : playback 1
00-02: ALC1150 Alt Analog : ALC1150 Alt Analog : capture 1
01-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
01-07: HDMI 1 : HDMI 1 : playback 1
01-08: HDMI 2 : HDMI 2 : playback 1
02-00: USB Audio : USB Audio : playback 1 : capture 1
```

arecord --list-pcms

```
sysdefault:CARD=Microphone
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Microphone,DEV=0
    Yeti Stereo Microphone, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

[image]
Under speakers the Yeti Microphone Shows up, but Under microphone's it does not. It only shows front, rear, and line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> gksu gvim /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Then comment out the line:

`# options snd-usb-audio index=-2`

> sudo alsa force-reload

After doing this the yeti microphone shows up in Audacity and Skype.

Comment: I had two of these, and commenting them out didn't change it for me
`snd-usb-audio index=-2` (Ubuntu 18.10)