# I cannot use the built in microphone of my laptop in 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: sound

I installed 18.04.2 LTS on my laptop and my microphone does not work anymore. Anyone knows how to fix that?

Here's what `sudo lshw -C sound` shows:

```
*-multimedia              
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:136 memory:b1228000-b122bfff memory:b1200000-b120ffff
```

Comment: What does `sudo lshw -C sound` show?

Comment: See above. I edited my question.

Comment: Will the Q or the A of https://askubuntu.com/questions/679739/yeti-usb-microphone-not-recognized-in-audacity-or-skype-14-10 help you?

Comment: unfortunately not